# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context - Google Sign In

Tags: swift, firebase, google-signin

With the code attached below, I often get the error **Type of expression is ambiguous without more context.** I've tried solving this by declaring types for the parameters but then I get the error **Cannot find 'user' in scope.** Any idea how I can fix this?

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: config, presenting: getRootViewController()) {[self] user, err in
                
                if let error = err {
                    isLoading = false
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                
                guard
                    let authentication = user?.authentication,
                    let idToken = authentication.idToken
                else {
                    isLoading = false
                    return
                }
                
                let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken,
                                                               accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
                //fifrebase auth
                Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { result, err in
                    isLoading = false
                    if let error = err {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    }
                    //displaying user name
                    guard let user = result?.user else {
                        return
                    }
                    print(user.displayName ?? "Success!")
                    // update user as logged in
                    withAnimation {
                        log_Status = true
                    }
                }
                
            }
```

Comment: How is this a SwiftUI error? Please change your title to something more relevant.

Comment: The question is a bit vague and needs more details. Did you step through the code line by line, examining the flow and vars along the way until you find something unexpected? What line is throwing the error?